# Simplifying surds

Tags: real-numbers

I got a question in my textbook that was to simplify the expression:
$6\sqrt{162c^7d^5}$, and the answer says it is $54c^3d^2\sqrt{2cd}$, but I'm not sure how this happened as $5^2\cdot162$ doesn't equal $54^2\cdot2$. ($c$ and $d$ are positive real numbers.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because $6^2\cdot 162=54^2\cdot 2$. (Your $5$ should be $6$.)

Comment: Ah okay, thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome!